# navigate to previous fragment on click on back button:

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have two fragment in my activity fragment1 and fragment2, i want when user click on back button from fragment2 it should navigate user to fragement1

My xml code for activity is: **I am setting fragment in xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Routeplan" >       
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/content_frame_polymer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >               


          <viewpager.helper.JazzyViewPager 
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"         
                />      

    </FrameLayout>   
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {

        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.packing_activity);
        mPager = (JazzyViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);      
        PagerAdapter padapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),NUM_PAGES,mPager);     
        mPager.setAdapter(padapter);        
        mPager.setPageMargin(30);       

    } 

}
```

PagerAdapter code:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    int NUM_PAGES;
    JazzyViewPager mPager;
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numPages, JazzyViewPager mPager) {
        super(fm);  
        this.NUM_PAGES=numPages;
        this.mPager=mPager;

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        mPager.setObjectForPosition(obj, position);
        return obj;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0) {
        case 0:                 
            return new Fragmentone();         

        case 1:                 
            return new Fragmenttwo();           

        default:
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

}
```

Fragmentone code:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment { 

    private ViewGroup rootView1;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {                

         return rootView1 = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.about_rohtak, container, false);

    }
}
```

Fragmenttwo code:

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment { 

    private ViewGroup rootView1;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {                

         return rootView1 = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.about_rohtak, container, false);

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Override onBackPressed in Activity
2) check current position of pager using getCurrentItem()
3) If position is 1 setCurrentItem to 0 using setCurrentItem(int item)
4) else finish activity

Comment: @Karn shah Thanks  .It worked for me

Comment: welcome manish. If it worked for you, vote up the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to override `onBackPressed` method on Activity and pass to process logic to Fragment. In Fragment you need to listen events which occurred in Activity. There is some options how to implement this things but I prefer to communicate through interfaces if possible. This could concrete implementation:

```
public MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BackButtonListener backButtonListener;

    public interface BackButtonListener {
        void onBackButtonClicked();
    }

    public void setBackButtonListener(BackButtonListener backButtonListener) {
        this.backButtonListener = backButtonListener;           
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (null != backButtonListener) {
            backButtonListener.onBackButtonClicked();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();      
        }
    }
}

public MyFragment extends Fragment implements BackButtonListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        if (activity instanceof MyActivity) {
            ((MyActivity) activity).setBackButtonListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void onBackButtonClicked() {
        if (0 != viewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edited**: be careful implementing this because you changing natural navigation order. Think how you handle back button then current item of viewpager is the first element (position 0). You should some how tell that fragment object (BackButtonListener) can't handle this and pass back to process logic to caller or do other things. It depends on situation. Shortly, always do something meaningful to app navigation on back button press.